# UITextField only allow letters and space and limit maximum characters

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

In text field I want to allow only letters and spaces. Following solution seems to work but it has couple of issues

1) It doesn't allow space

2) It counts the numbers when entered and includes in total count for maximum limit which is not correct. We should only count what we see in the field

I've been searching for a solution but most of them seem to be outdated or doesn't fit for the purpose.
Any help?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Don't allow number in name field
    if textField == nameTextField && string.count > 0 {
        let textString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let LettersOnly = NSCharacterSet.letters
        let strValid = LettersOnly.contains(UnicodeScalar.init(string)!)
        return strValid && textString.count <= 30
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Point 2 is unclear. Your code only allows 30 characters. In what way is the limit not working as expected?

Comment: It's explained clearly that it includes number in count. How else to explain it? If you hit, let's say, 2 on keyboard 30 times it reaches the limit which is not what we want. We want to count the letters and spaces entered not the numbers.

Comment: Now it's even more confusing. Your code doesn't allow numbers, just letters.

Comment: Yes code looks like doing it job, pop it in a project and see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use something like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.letters.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: " "))
    let maxLength = 10

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        // check characters
        guard newText.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) == nil else { return false }

        // check length
        guard newText.count <= maxLength else { return false }

        return true
    }

}
```

Or even shorter:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return (newText.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) == nil) && (newText.count <= maxLength)
}
```

Comment: Not my vote but good answers explain what was wrong and explain how the answer solves the problem. Please don't just post code. No one learns as much this way.